# Line break gone after XSLT transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

My XML:

```
<root>
  <summary>
     <article_1>some data&#xA;</article_1>
  </summary>
  <summary>
     <article_1>some data&#xA;</article_1>
  </summary>
  .
  .
  .
</root>
```

I am trying to copy all summary tags to separate files, but when XSLT transformation is done I am loosing line breaks in the newly created files.

My XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="no" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="summary">
  <xsl:result-document href="{@summary}.xml">
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What am I doing wrong, and why are there no line breaks in my newly created XML anymore?

Comment: On an aside note, your stylesheet is XSLT 1.0 (version="1.0"), but xsl:result-document requires XSLT 2.0. See http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116 and http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/REC-xslt20-20070123. I also notice that the template that matches summary elements is selecting summary/node(), so I don't see how it will select anything (since a summary element does not have child summary elements).

Comment: My mistake. I have corrected code above. Thanks for notecing.

Answer (score 2):

The newline character is treated as white space, whether you encode it or not. You can add the directive:

```
<xsl:preserve-space elements="article_1"/>
```

to make sure that the white space is preserved.

Comment: Isn't this on by default, and necessary only if xsl:strip-space is present?

Comment: I would have said that it is on by default. If the `preserve-space` element doesn't make a difference, try it on `summary` element. O/w I'm not sure what is happening.

Comment: Most likely the OP views the result documents in a browser, where automatic "improvements" are applied to an XML document - as removing "unnecessary" newlines. (p.s. `xsl:preserve-space` does not solve this problem).

Comment: Note that i am not viewing output in web browser, but XML editor.

Answer (score 1):

If your XML input uses CDATA, you can do  **linefeed-treatment="preserve"** in your XSL

Example: 
XML input

```
<data>
  <Alert>
        <![CDATA[PredniOD
         Ca32mg Mane
         Cholenthly]]>
   </Alert>
</data>
```

XSL 1.0

```
<fo:block linefeed-treatment="preserve">
     <xsl:value-of select="data/Alert" />
 </fo:block>
```

Output

```
 PredniOD
 Ca32mg Mane
 Cholenthly
```

Other useful ones

white-space-collapse="false"
white-space-treatment="preserve"

Comment: Finally, after hours finding convoluted answers to solve this problem using XSLT 1.0 it was just as simple as this ... Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You do not lose any line breaks (new lines, that is), even if they appear to have vanished.

Assuming a sensible **input XML**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <summary number="1">
   <article_1>text1&#xA;</article_1>
  </summary>
  <summary number="2">
   <article_1>text2&#xA;</article_1>
  </summary>
  <!--...-->
</root>
```

And this **stylesheet** (this is in XSLT 2.0, as you use `result-document()`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

     <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"/>

     <xsl:template match="summary">
       <xsl:result-document href="{@number}.xml">
         <xsl:copy-of select="." />
       </xsl:result-document>
     </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This results in several **output documents**, like the one named `1.xml` shown here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><summary number="1">
  <article_1>text1
  </article_1>
</summary>
```

As you can see, there is still a new line. It is no longer encoded as an entity reference (`&#xA;`), but translated to an actual break. If you are looking at the result files with a browser like Firefox, it might trick you into thinking that the newlines are no longer there, but that's only formatting automatically applied by the brower's parser.

---

Note that your post has severe issues besides the newline problem.

- As the name of an output XML file, you select `@summary`, yet in your input XML there is no such attribute. In the input I have shown there is a `number` attribute which is translated into the file names.
- You are using the `result-document()` function that is available only in XSLT 2.0 (i.e. with an XSLT 2.0 processor). Why then is your stylesheet in `version="1.0"`?

Comment: what happens if i process this xml further?

Comment: This is too broad a question to be answered here, I'm afraid. It depends on the nature of the post-processing. Why don't you process it further and come back to SO with another question, in case you encounter any problems?

Comment: If i process this xml, lets assume that line breaks will stay. Than i try to process XML further for my one customer which need these line breaks, but i can not supply him new XML with them as in further process they get erased. The real question now is how to preserve line breaks in further processing?

Comment: Then either a) see to it that whitespace is not removed while processing the XMl further or b) do away with storing significant whitespace in such an "ugly" way and find a good alternative (like storing whitespace in separate elements).

Answer (score 0):

I have got the variable in XSLT with the line-breaks preserved. But when transformed to HTML using XSL, line-breaks are not preserved. Then understood to use

```
<pre> 
     <xsl:value-of select="$VariableName" disable-output-escaping="yes"/> 
</pre>
```

Now able to preserve the  line breaks as it comes from the source